# Swift / how to check for reachability

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code to check for reachability:

```
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        xy
    } else {
        yz
    }
```

My problem is, that the reachability always is false, if the device **IS NOT** inside a Wlan network. In regular gsm reachability is always false.

How can I fix this? Help is very appreciated.

This is my Reachabilty helper:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

        return isReachable && !needsConnection

    }
}
```

Comment: Which library you're using?

Comment: omg my bad. just a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using almost the same code.

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }) else {
            return false
        }

        var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
        let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }

}
```

Comment: replaced mine with your code and it works now. that's all I wanted. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I'm using, it seems to work perfectly for me:

In your Main View Controller:

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == false {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

In a separate class:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
    let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

    return isReachable && !needsConnection

}
}
```